# Forwarding SMS from Twilio # to Super Sim

Tags: api, twilio, iot, cellular-network

I have some issues forwarding sms from my # to my sim. I have tried a few things and cannot get it to work. Here's what I've got so far. Is it even possible to do this in the console with a super sim? [pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjyG6.png)
[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csPsI.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working today using a studio flow and assign the flow to your twilio number.

In the flow, trigger a http post to the super sim http post url - https://username:password@supersim.twilio.com/v1/SmsCommands

- select POST
  -Form url encoded
  -http parameters must include:
  (key) Sim & value = Sim #
  (key) Payload & value = {{trigger.message.Body}} ** this will forward the body to your sim.

**if you are getting an authentication fault, you may need to include an Authorization parameter as another header.

Hopefully this helps.